# Perl Regex OR condition

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable which is like $var = 1.2.3 or $var = Variable/1.2.3. I am trying to write a regex that matches and stores in $1. The code goes as follows:

```
 if ($var =~ m/[\w+\/\d+.\d+.\d+])/){
     $a = $1;
 }
```

I want to match in the above condition if any of the $var prevails. Please suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Perhaps you could add some examples of input and desired match.

Comment: If you want to match a literal `.` then you need to backslash-escape it in your regex, e.g. `m/\./` instead of `m/./`

Comment: Or as daxim did in his answer, put the dot in brackets: `m/[.]/`

Comment: You said - *matches and stores in $1.*. Well, matches what? Do you want the version as output, or the whole string?

Comment: @theglauber Rohit has explained and solve the problem..The actual problem was to extarct $var based on whether it is either 1.2.3 or Variable/1.2.3..After comparing if it matches either of the style store it in $a i.e $1. Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove that character class. A character classes matches just a single character. It doesn't represent any sequence. Also, `.` is a meta-character in regex. To match it literally, you need to escape it.

And then, you need to make the part before `/` as optional, using `?` quantifier, as it is not necessarily present in string:

```
if ($var =~ m/((?:\w+\/)?\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/){
    $a = $1;
}
```

Just FYI, you can use any delimiter for match operator, so as to avoid escaping `/`:

```
m!((?:\w+/)?\d+\.\d+\.\d+)!
```

Answer (score 2):

[Parentheses capture](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Parentheses-for-capturing). It is error-prone to rely on `$1`, simply use the return value from the `m`atch operator.

```
for my $var ('1.2.3', 'Variable/1.2.3') {
    if (my ($version) = $var =~ m{
        (?:\A | /)            # beginning of string or a slash
        (\d+ [.] \d+ [.] \d+) # capture version number triple
        \z                    # end of string
    }msx) {
        print ">>> $version <<<\n";
    }
}
__END__
>>> 1.2.3 <<<
>>> 1.2.3 <<<
```

Comment: Or `m{(?:^|/)(\d+ [.] \d+ [.] \d+)$}x` if it should be anchored (e.g. if validation is required).

Comment: Good idea, added into the answer

Comment: @daxim: I take the above variables from an array. Hence, the above for loop will create confusion. What do you think??

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if ($var =~ m/(?>[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*+\/)?+[0-9]++\.[0-9]++\.[0-9]++/i) {
     $a = $&;
 }
```